# "No traceback available" within Intellij Debugger for R

Tags: r, intellij-idea

I:s there any way to see errors for `watch` variables within Intellij? All I can see presently is `No traceback available`:

[image]

When I looked into stacktraces and debugging for `R` it seems they are limited and somewhat primitive - but are actually actively worked on for improvement. I am wondering if any settings "help" here for informative error messsages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  developer has responded that the `R` plugin is not feature complete: this is expected behavior presently.